# Как открыть ссылку в браузере по умолчанию, если в ней target=_blank?

Tags: delphi-7, delphi, webbrowser, borland

Здравствуйте, подскажите как сделать так, чтобы если в ссылке стоит `target=_blank`, то ссылка бы открылась не в IE а в браузере по умолчанию? Помогите.

Comment: Стандартный браузер? Не, не слышал. По-моему IE - стандартней некуда. Может, браузер по-умолчанию?

Comment: извините за неточность, конечно-же в браузере по умолчанию

Comment: эта команда открывает страницу в браузере поумолчанию  
    
    ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('адрес сайта'), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);

Comment: @teanЫЧ, у меня эта команда открывает ссылку в IE, по-умолчанию стоит Chrome